# Recursion - Removing Duplicates

Tags: java

I'm working on a method which removes duplicates of an element in an ArrayList, recursively. But I'm running into a bit of a problem, my method works and removes some elements, but not all of the duplicates.

Here's my the input:

```
100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 300, 100, 500, 500, 400, 100, 400, 100, 100
```

And here's the output:

```
100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 500, 100
```

And my method:

```
public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list, int counter){
    if(list == null){
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    if(counter < list.size()){
        if(list.contains(list.get(counter))){
            list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(list.get(counter)));
        }
        removeDuplicates(list, ++counter);
    }
}
```

I understand that I'm only removing the last element of said value, and then iterating to the next one. I was wondering how I should change this to remove all elements that are duplicates. Also, one part of my output that confuses me is, there are three values of '400', yet only one shows up in the [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKQb5.png).

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is worth noting that recursion is completely unnecessary here, and doesn't really buy you anything. Furthermore, your algorithm is very inefficient. Is there a reason you're doing things this way?

Comment: Why don't you use a HashSet?

Comment: If you remove a element from ArrayList, the size of the list will be one smaller.

Comment: It's for an assignment, we have to do this with recursion. I understand that a HashSet would work wonders, and that my code is completely inefficient but we're not worried about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

```
    public static void removeDuplicates(ArrayList<Integer> list, int counter){


        if(list == null){
            throw new NullPointerException();
        }

        if(counter < list.size()){
            if(list.contains(list.get(counter))){
                if(list.lastIndexOf(list.get(counter))!=counter)
                {
                    list.remove(list.lastIndexOf(list.get(counter)));
                    counter--;
                }
            }
            removeDuplicates(list, ++counter);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Beside that @NPE is right (I assume this is homework), you should consider to call your function as long with the **very same** head, as long there is a duplicated element found. Use the next element (i.e., increase `counter`) only, if no duplicate is found (anymore).

Answer (score 1):

`list.remove()` will reduce `list.size()`, meaning everytime you remove an item and advance `counter`, you'll end up skipping one.

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why are you using recursion?  Much simpler to simply build a new list from the old one.

If you work through the sequence of calls, deleting the items from your string, you will find that the output is as expected.

Pass 1 removes the last 100

> 100, 200, 200, 300, 400, 300, 100, 500, 500, 400, 100, 400, 100

Pass 2 removes the last 200

> 100, 200, 300, 400, 300, 100, 500, 500, 400, 100, 400, 100

Pass 3 removes the last 300

> 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 500, 500, 400, 100, 400, 100

Pass 4 removes the last 400

> 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 500, 500, 400, 100, 100

Pass 5 removes the last 100

> 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 500, 500, 400, 100

Pass 6 removes the last 500

> 100, 200, 300, 400, 100, 500, 400, 100

Pass 7 removes nothing
Pass 8 removes nothing

Answer (score 0):

try

```
    if (counter < list.size()) {
        int i = list.lastIndexOf(list.get(counter));
        if (i > counter) {
            list.remove(i);
        } else {
            counter++;
        }
        removeDuplicates(list, counter);
    }
```